# Reverse generating function for $a_n = (-1)^n C_{2n}^n 4^{-n}$

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions

Task.
Let $A(t)$ and $B(t)$ be generating functions of sequences ${a_n} = (-1)^n C_{2n}^n 4^{-n}$ and ${b_n}$.
Let $A(t)B(t) = 1$.
Find $b_n$ and $B(t)$.

I try do next:
$A(t)B(t) = 1 =>$
$$
\begin{cases}
a_0b_0 = 1 \\
a_0b_1 + a_1b_0 = 0 \\
a_0 b_2 + a_1b_1 + a_2 b_0 = 0 \\
... \\
\sum_{k=0}^n a_k b_{n - k} = 0
\end{cases}
$$

\begin{cases}
b_0 = 1/ a_0 = 1 \\
b_1 = -a_1\\
b_2 = - a_1b_1 - a_2 b_0  \\
... \\
b_n = -\sum_{k=1}^n a_k b_{n - k} 
\end{cases}

I try to find explicit formula for $b_n$, but I have no idea how to do it. Could u help me, please?

Comment: What is $C_{2n}^n$?

Comment: This is number of combinations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing $\binom{2n}{n}$ for $C_{2n}^n$, we have
$$A(t) = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n t^n = \sum_{n \ge 0} \binom{2n}{n} (-t/4)^n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t}},$$
so
$$B(t) = \frac{1}{A(t)} = \sqrt{1+t} = \sum_{n \ge 0} \binom{1/2}{n} t^n,$$
yielding $b_n = \binom{1/2}{n}$.

Comment: Oh, It does't seem too complicated as I imagined before! Thank u!